# Java:How invoke implementclass's element in interface?

Tags: java

The class Framework:

```
public class Tree<AnyType extends Comparable <? super AnyType>> {
    private static class BinaryNode<AnyType>{}

    private BinaryNode<AnyType> root;
    public Tree(){}
    public void makeEmpty(){}
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        /*code*/
    }
    public boolean contains(AnyType x){
        /*code*/
    }
    public boolean contains(AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> node){
        /*code*/
    }
}
```

I want to create a interface, but the BinaryNode is private:

```
public interface TreeFramework<AnyType> {
    public void makeEmpty();
    public boolean isEmpty();
    public boolean contains(AnyType x);
    public boolean contains(AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> e);   //fail
}
```

Do I have to create a public BinaryNode class?

Comment: Lets step back: why do you want to create such an interface? The point of BinaryNode is: it is an inner detail of that implementation; obviously not meant to be used outside of the class? So, what would the purpose of that 4th method in your interface?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the use of an interface. Generally you should not need `BinaryNode` inside your interface.

Comment: @GhostCat I want to know whether like `super` exist to invoke.Trees are mostly because of the BinaryNode.

Comment: @zhanzezhu Binary trees are. But in general: no. And sorry, no idea what you mean invoking super.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that I see is that you are getting a compiler error because client code cannot find any BinaryNode classes to import. You could always accept a plain old `java.lang.Object`, and use the Object#equals() method to determine equality like most of the standard library collections.

Looking at your interface design, I don't see how client code could get access to a BinaryNode reference within the Tree class. Unless this interface is incomplete, exposing the BinaryNode class in the contains method seems to not do much for a potential client.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I remove the **private**,become `public boolean contains(AnyType x, Tree.BinaryNode<AnyType> e);`Do not?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? I don't see a method that returns a BinaryNode. As long as code doesn't have a reference to a BinaryNode, the client code won't find this interface useful. If there is a method, I would recommend created a separate file with a bare bones interface. This makes it easy for code to grow as you add new functionality to these classes.